# MatLab-Finding error in hough line transform

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, hough-transform, canny-edge-detector

Can I calculate the number of error in Hough Line Transform using MatLab? I did Hough Line Transform process from Canny Edge Detection, but it is unable to detect all the lines.
Thanks.[image: output]

Comment: The *"...number of error..."* in what sense? Can you post a representative example of input / output images and what you perceive as "odd" in this case?

Comment: I mean, can i calculate the error of hough line transform? because there is some lines missed out from line segmentation. thank you